# Where should I post a question about school exchanges?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about a school exchange and was wondering on what site I should post it. The question is called:

**What should I do if my exchange partner follows a religious etiquette and I don't?**

Does anyone know where I should post this?

Comment: Not really sure there's any site that would be a good fit here. And well, in this case I'd actually recommend checking with your partner or appropriate person organising it first

Comment: If the focus is on the religion part, you can ask in the specific religion site, e.g. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/ or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What is an exchange partner? We all are your (stack)exchange partners. ;-) Btw, I think you have luck and not a problem.

Comment: @peterh an exchange partner is the person who's house you stay in and vice verca while on the trip